# Get sublayers from group layer with Python in Gimp

Tags: python, layer, gimp, xcf, python-fu

I have an XCD file with a nested layers structure:

```
image
    front-layer
    content-layer
        content-layer-name-1
        content-layer-name-2
        content-layer-name-3
    back-layer
```

I open the file with `image = pdb.gimp_file_load(xcf_file, xcf_file)` and can get `front-layer`, `content-layer` and `back-layer` as `image.layers[0]`, `image.layers[1]` and `image.layers[2]`. But Gimp can't get sublayers in `content-layer` by list index.

I can use `pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, 'content-layer-name-3')`, but I don't known the layers' names.

I try `pdb.gimp_item_get_children(image.layers[1])`, but this method return `INT32ARRAY` with the item's list of children and I haven't found how retrieve the item by its id.

How can I get sublayers from a group layer with Python in Gimp (2.8)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GIMP Python went mostly unmaintained over this development cycle  (you can blame much of that on myself).

One of the few updates done was the creation of the "Item" class - and the implementation of a class method on it that allows one to use the numeric ID returned by the PDB methods to retreive an item.

So, you can use, like you found out `pdb.gimp_item_get_children(group_layer)`, and on the
returned ID for the children use `gimp.Item.from_id` to retrieve the actual layer.

Here is a GIMP console section where I retrieve a sublayer "by hand":

```
>>> img = gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> c = img.layers[0]
>>> c
<gimp.Layer 'Layer Group'>
>>> pdb.gimp_item_get_children(c)
(1, (4,))
>>> c2 = gimp.Item.from_id(4)
>>> c2
<gimp.Layer 'cam2'>
>>>
```

** **update** **

I spent some hacking hours, and GIMP 2.8 final will come with proper support for Layer Groups - you will need the  hack above up to gimp 2.8 RC 1, but if you build the project from git master right now, layer groups show as instances of "GroupLayer", and feature a "layers" attribute which works just like the "layers" attribute in an image.

[commit 75242a03e45ce751656384480e747ca30d728206](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/commit/?id=75242a03e45ce751656384480e747ca30d728206)

```
 Date:   Fri Apr 20 04:49:16 2012 -0300

     pygimp: adds proper support for layer groups

     Layer groups where barely supported using numeric IDs and
     by calling gimp.Item.from_id. This adds a Python
     GroupLayer class.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the breakdown, I was struggling with the same issue as I am in the process of updating my plug-ins from 2.6 to 2.7~2.8. Here is the edited function:

```
def find_layer_by_name (image, name):
for layer in image.layers:
    #check if layer is a group and drill down if it is
    if pdb.gimp_item_is_group(layer):
        gr = layer
        gr_items = pdb.gimp_item_get_children(layer)
        for index in gr_items[1]:
            item = gimp.Item.from_id(index)
            if item.name == name:
                return item

    # if layer is on the first level     
    if layer.name == name:
        return layer
        return None
```

Comment: You can just check for the "layers" attribute now, and retrieve sub-layers from there. Keep in mind that there might be more than 2 levels of layers, as in groups containing other groups.